# Problem with Greek

Tags: babel, greek

I have a problem with Greek in pdflatex. It appeared first time a few weeks ago when I updated Miktex using the package manager. Then after a new update it disappeared and finally after the last update (07 Sept 2016) it appeared again.

The minimum working example is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{Kerkis}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\title{ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΜΑΓΝΗΤΙΣΜΟΣ-ΟΠΤΙΚΗ}
\date{08 Σεπτεμβρίου 2016.}
\author{Ανδρέας Ζούπας}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
 Διάρκεια Εξέτασης \textbf{3.0} ώρες.

\end{document}
```

I had been working with it with no problem before the updates. Here's my log file:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.18 \maketitle
? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
LaTeX Warning: Command \textEpsilon invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textKappa invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textTau invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textRho invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textOmicron invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textMu invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textAlpha invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textNu invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textEta invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textTau invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textIota invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textMu invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textOmicron invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textOmicron invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textTau invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textIota invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textKappa invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textEta invalid in math mode on input line 18.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.18 \maketitle
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.18 \maketitle
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@maketitle ...note \thanks {\LARGE \@title \par }
                                                  \vskip 1.5em{\large \lines...
l.18 \maketitle
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.18 \maketitle
LaTeX Warning: Command \ensuregreek invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \acctonos invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textZeta invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textomicron invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \ensuregreek invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \acctonos invalid in math mode on input line 18.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<template> \unskip \hfil }
                          \hskip \tabcolsep \endtemplate
l.18 \maketitle
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.18 \maketitle
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.18 \maketitle
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.18 \maketitle
LaTeX Warning: Command \ensuregreek invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \acctonos invalid in math mode on input line 18.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textomicron invalid in math mode on input line 18.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\@maketitle ...ar}\par }\vskip 1em{\large \@date }
                                                  \end {center}\par \vskip 1...
l.18 \maketitle
! LaTeX Error: Command \end{center} invalid in math mode.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.18 \maketitle
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.18 \maketitle
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.18 \maketitle
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.18 \maketitle
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.18 \maketitle
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.19  \Delta
             \iota ά\rho \kappa \varepsilon \iota \alpha  Ε\xi έ\tau \alp...
LaTeX Warning: Command \ensuregreek invalid in math mode on input line 19.
LaTeX Warning: Command \acctonos invalid in math mode on input line 19.
LaTeX Warning: Command \textEpsilon invalid in math mode on input line 19.
LaTeX Warning: Command \ensuregreek invalid in math mode on input line 19.
LaTeX Warning: Command \acctonos invalid in math mode on input line 19.
LaTeX Warning: Command \ensuregreek invalid in math mode on input line 19.
LaTeX Warning: Command \acctonos invalid in math mode on input line 19.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $


_____________________________________________________________________*
```

To make sure that I was not doing anything fundamentally wrong, I decided to use the same structure but with English. The working example is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{Kerkis}    
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\title{\en ELECTROMAGNETISM-OPTICS}    
\date{\en 08 September 2016.}    
\author{\en Andreas Zoupas}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\en
Exam Duration \textbf{3.0} hours.

\end{document}
```

However, this one runs with not problem at all.

I made changes suggested to me and run the code with shareLateX and it did run ok. I think it is a problem with the MiKTeX package babel-greek but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Well, apart from the `Kerkis` package that I don't have, your example runs fine with me. So I assume that package might be conflicting in some way. Where can we get it?

Comment: Works fine for me (and I do have the Kerkis package), show the real log-file, not only the terminal output.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unrelated, but do you know why on earth MiKTeX has `bblopts.cfg` from `arabi` in runtime?

Comment: No error for me; however the package should be named `kerkis` (all lowercase) and the order of the packages is wrong: use the order `inputenc`, `babel`, `kerkis`, `natbib`, `graphicx` (and don't pass it the option `pdftex`). This doesn't affect the output, but is preferable for better organization of the input. Please, add `\errorcontextlines=100` at the very beginning of the failing code and report the error message (not the full log, this time).

Comment: @egreg arabi on CTAN has a bblopts.cfg and so it got in the miktex package. Probably someone from the texlive team removed it when packaging for texlive.

Comment: @Alenanno This is a typical package of greek fonts. I do not know what distribution you have but it is included in MiKTex. Thank you for your Answer

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for your comment. I did everything you suggested but still, I get the same error. And a question, how do I just report the error message?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you for your comment. What do you mean when you say the real log-file? I had the impression that this was what I uploaded.. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to wrong installation of some MiKTeX package

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the root of the problem. In Winedt 10 there is ContribManager which allows users to install Macros or Programs. I had the MathGreek installed which apparently messed all my greek encoding up. I uninstalled it and everything runs ok now. The only problem is that in many latex files I use, I think that uninstalling MathGreek caused every greek character in the file to be substituted with the corresponding latex command. E.g. υ--> \upsilon..... This should be a lesson for the future for me. Thank you all!!