# Problem Running pdfTeX File from local Directory

Tags: pdftex, babel

Trying to fix an issue I have with Greek and pdfLaTeX ([Problem with Greek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328624/problem-with-greek)) I downloaded the file: http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/greek/greek-inputenc/greek-utf8.tex

When running it from the Temp Directory (I did not save it I just opened it with WinEdt directly) it runs ok and I get no errors at all (I am using pdflatex on the Latest update of MiKTeX 2.9.) but when I save it in a local directory and try to run it, it gives errors! This is something I do not understand at all!

A minimum example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}=
\begin{document}
\subsection{Other Unicode Blocks}
\begin{description}
\item [Latin-1 Supplement]: \ensuregreek{¨ « ¯ ´   · »}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

and the errors and Warnings I get are the following:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.30 ...ent]: \ensuregreek{¨ « ¯ ´   \cdot »}

? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...

LaTeX Warning: Command \guillemotright invalid in math mode on input line 30.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\T1\ensuregreek #1->\leavevmode {\greekscript #1}

l.30 ...ent]: \ensuregreek{¨ « ¯ ´   \cdot »}


! LaTeX Error: Command \end{description} invalid in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.46 \end{description}


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.46 \end{description}


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.46 \end{description}

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.46 \end{description}

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.46 \end{description}
```

I hope this helps in understanding what the problem is.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is probably effect of saving the file in format not compatible with UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I did save it ina format compatible with UTF-8. I am using WinEdt and the document properties are the following: Document Mode TeX:UNIX:UTF-8, Document Format UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error message seems to be pretty clear:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.231 ...ent]: \ensuregreek{Â¨ Â« Â¯ Â´  \cdot Â»}
```

The macro `\ensuregreek` does not say anything about math, but `\cdot` is a math macro, thus `$\cdot$` might fix this error (and likely some followup errors because of math mode, which was enabled by TeX as error recovery from the first error).

Comment: The part of the code giving the error is                                                                                    \subsection{Other Unicode Blocks}
\begin{description}
\item [Latin-1 Supplement]: \ensuregreek{¨ « ¯ ´   · »} ....\end{description}                                                                        do you think this is still related to missing math enclosing symbols?          Since this is part of large file perhaps i should try to get a minimum (not) working example out of it... but the real problem was that it run ok from the temp dir.....

Comment: I just got a minimum example up and the errors. I hope this helps

Comment: @AndreasZoupas The minimal document does not create any errors.

Comment: @Przemysław Scherwentke, I think I found the root of the problem. In Winedt 10 there is  ContribManager  which allows users to install Macros or Programms. I had the MathGreek installed which apparently messed all my greek encoding up. I uninstalled it and everything runs ok now. The only problem is that in many latex files I use, I think that uninstalling MathGreek  caused every greek character in the file to be substituted with the corresponding latex command. E.g. υ--> \upsilon..... this should be a lesson for the future for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the root of the problem. In Winedt 10 there is ContribManager which allows users to install Macros or Programms. I had the MathGreek installed which apparently messed all my greek encoding up. I uninstalled it and everything runs ok now. The only problem is that in many latex files I use, I think that uninstalling MathGreek caused every greek character in the file to be substituted with the corresponding latex command. E.g. υ--> \upsilon..... this should be a lesson for the future for me.

This solves also the other problem i posted: [Problem with Greek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328624/problem-with-greek)